# Searching a red black tree through text file

Tags: java, red-black-tree

I am working on a school project and it's dictionary application using red black tree.. so the program reads a text file and every line has only one word.
when i do my search it gives me that the word is not available if i entered it with different letters size.. for example if the file has the word "Lion" and i searched "lion" in my program it says that the word is not available in dictionary.. here is my search method. And help me please to fix that.

```
public static int search(Node root,String data)
{ 
    while(!root.isNullLeaf)
{    String temporary=root.data;
    if(temporary.equals(data))
    {
        System.out.print("yaaay "+ root.data +" is found\n");
        return 0;
    }
   if(temporary.compareTo(data)>0)
       root=root.left;

     if(temporary.compareTo(data)<0)
       root=root.right;

}
    System.out.println("ouch "+ data+ " not found\n");
    return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `XXXIgnoreCase` functions fore these type of requirements

`temporary.equals(data)` becomes `temporary.equalsIgnoreCase(data)` and `temporary.compareTo(data)` becomes `temporary.compareToIgnoreCase(data)`

I also corrected parts of the code to simplify your logic

```
public static int search(Node root,String data) { 
    while(!root.isNullLeaf) {    
        String temporary=root.data;
        if(temporary.equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
            System.out.print("yaaay "+ root.data +" is found\n");
            return 0;
        }
        int compareResult = temporary.compareToIgnoreCase(data);
        if(compareResult > 0)
            root = root.left;
        else
            root = root.right;   
    }
    System.out.println("ouch "+ data+ " not found\n");
    return 1;
}
```